# Error C1189 when compiling OpenCV for arm64 at amd64

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile OpenCV with MS Visual Studio C++ (17) for arm64 on a windows x64 host and constantly getting, whatever I try, this:

```
fatal  error C1189: #error:  This header is specific to X86, X64, ARM64, and ARM64EC targets
```

I set up the environment with:

```
vsdevcmd -arch=arm64 -host_arch=amd64
```

Here's my .bat for compiling:

```
:: setting the CL env variable makes no difference:
:: set CL=/D_M_ARM64=1
:: set CL=/arch:armv8.8
set CL=
echo
echo extra vars for compiler: %CL%
echo
set 'CMAKE_GENERATOR_OPTIONS=-G"Visual Studio 17 2022"'
set "CMAKE_OPTIONS=-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_CUDA:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_python=OFF -DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF"
:: this is required to find the correct compiler!
set "CMAKE_ARCHITECTURE=-A ARM64"
cd opencv-4.5.4
rmdir /s build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. %CMAKE_GENERATOR_OPTIONS% %CMAKE_ARCHITECTURE% %CMAKE_OPTIONS%
:: cmake .. %CMAKE_GENERATOR_OPTIONS% %CMAKE_OPTIONS%
cd ..
cmake --build build --config Release
```

I get tons of these:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\emmintrin.h(20,1): fatal  error C11
89: #error:  This header is specific to X86, X64, ARM64, and ARM64EC targets (compiling source file C:\Users\v-sriikonen\open
cv\opencv-4.5.4\modules\core\src\async.cpp) [C:\Users\v-sriikonen\opencv\opencv-4.5.4\build\modules\world\opencv_world.vcxpro
j]
```

Emphasis on:

```
fatal  error C1189: #error:  This header is specific to X86, X64, ARM64, and ARM64EC targets
```

Which is stupid, since we're compiling exactly for ARM64.

Taking a look at those windows headers, I can see that:

```
#if !defined(_M_IX86) && !defined(_M_X64) && !(defined(_M_ARM64) && defined(USE_SOFT_INTRINSICS))
#error This header is specific to X86, X64, ARM64, and ARM64EC targets
#endif
```

So it seems that the preprocessor doesn't define `_M_ARM64` - which it should as we have the correct environment.  This is also manifested when cmake runs:

```
Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32822.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32822.0
...
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/arm64/cl.exe - skipped
...
-- Detected processor: AMD64
...
```

Comment: crossposted here: https://forum.opencv.org/t/cross-compiling-arm64-with-visual-studio/14384

Answer (score 0):

```
-DCV_ENABLE_INTRINSICS=OFF \
-DENABLE_SSE=OFF \
-DENABLE_SSE2=OFF \
-DENABLE_SSE3=OFF \
-DENABLE_SSE41=OFF \
-DENABLE_SSE42=OFF \
-DENABLE_SSSE3=OFF
```

Fix is disable intrinsics for the moment on that target
Add this to your cmake options